# Using case expression in SELECT when using TOP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select only the top 50 records when my customer is a certain customer.  Otherwise select all records.  I have the following (a simplified version).  I am on SQL Server 2000.  Can this be done?

```
DECLARE @custnum AS VARCHAR(7)
SET @custnum = '1234567'
SELECT CASE @custnum 
        WHEN '1234567' THEN [TOP 50 DISTINCT]
        ELSE [DISTINCT]
        END
        item1, item2
FROM myTable
WHERE myCust = @custnum
```

Answer (score 2):

How about parameterizing the TOP count? It's still an ugly hack, but at least you only need one query.

```
DECLARE @custnum AS VARCHAR(7)
DECLARE @topcount as int

SET @custnum = '1234567'
SELECT @topcount = CASE WHEN @custnum = '1234567' THEN '50' ELSE 2147483647 END
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@topcount) 
    item1, item2
FROM myTable
WHERE myCust = @custnum
```

Edit: Sorry, just realized this was for SQL Server 2000. In which case this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Like that you can't do it!

But you can do it with a IF ELSE statements.

Pseudo-Code:

```
IF @custnum = '1234567'
SELECT [TOP 50 DISTINCT]
        item1, item2
FROM myTable
WHERE myCust = @custnum
ELSE
SELECT [DISTINCT]
        item1, item2
FROM myTable
WHERE myCust = @custnum
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `case` to change the syntax of a query. In SQL Server 2005 you can use an expression for `top`, but not in SQL Server 2000.

You would have to make two separate queries:

```
declare @custnum varchar(7)
set @custnum = '1234567'

if (@custnum = '1234567') begin
  select top 50 distict item1, item2
  from myTable
  where myCust = @custnum
end else begin
  select distinct item1, item2
  from myTable
  where myCust = @custnum
end
```